# Como adicionar a classe active em um site onepage?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, bootstrap-4

Boa boite, pessoal. Eu tenho um site onepage que possui um menu no modo sticky-top, gostaria de saber como eu faço para adicionar s classe "active" via JS da forma correta de acordo com a página que esta sendo visualizada no momento.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-color4 shadow sticky-top" id="navbar">
<div class="container">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
        <img src="img/cafe.png" alt="spella icon" class="w-35 invert-img">
    </a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
        <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link nav-text scroll" href="#home">Home <span class="sr-only">(Home)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link nav-text scroll" href="#about">About</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link scroll" href="#menu">Menu</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link scroll" href="#comments">Comments</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link scroll" href="#map">Map</a>
        </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Esse é o meu codigo JS, ele esta fazendo a função do scroll suave, mas gostaria que adicionasse a função de adicionar a classe "active" no menu.

```
var $doc = $('html, body');
$('.scroll').click(function () {
    $doc.animate({ scrollTop: $($.attr(this, 'href')).offset().top }, 500);
    $($doc).toggleClass("active");
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Não entendi ao certo em qual ação você pretende alterar adicionar a class para active.

tenta isso:

```
$(function () {
            var nav = $('#navbar');
            $(window).scroll(function () {
                if ($(this).scrollTop() > 500) {
                    nav.addClass("active");
                } else {
                    nav.removeClass("active");
                }
            });
        });
```

caso não atenda, explica o que gostaria que acontesse com o navbar e em qual ação.

espero que ajude